# Phonegap \ Cordova 1.6.0

Tags: cordova

Can anyone provide me with a dmg file for cordova 1.6.0? I am having nothing but problems trying to get through the MAKE process on my MAC and admittedly, am still quite new to mac development.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cordova 1.6.0 was released and has a DMG. Download on PhoneGap site: http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 2):

Release 1.6.0 is not out yet. DMG will be coming as soon as we cut the release.